How to say "position absolute and bottom 0%" in Jetpack Compose?
I am coming from a CSS background, so I want to have a screen where I have a button that's positioned at the very bottom of the screen.
In CSS, we can say:
.button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%
}

This will push the button to the end of the screen.
I wanted to achieve the same thing in Jetpack compose, but the API is pretty much overly complicated with hundreds of thousands of classes, just to design a basic layout.
Code:
Box {
    Column {
        Text("I am at the top left")
        Text("I want to be at the bottom left, but I don't know how")
    }
}

In CSS:


#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ddd;
  position: relative;
}

.bl {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
}
<div id="container">
  <button class="tl">Top left</button>
  <p>Stuff in between</p>
  <button class="bl">Bottom left</button>
</div>




So the solution was to use Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomStart), however, you need to wrap your Text composable with a parent wrapper such as a Box.
Summary:
Box(modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {
   Text("bottom left", modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomStart))
}

Full example:
Box(
    modifier =
        Modifier.fillMaxSize() // This will make the Box fill the entire screen
            .background(Color.Gray) // Set the background color of the Box
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.TopStart) // Align column to top start
    ) {
        Text("I am at the top left")
    }
    Button(
        onClick = { /* Do something */},
        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomStart) // Align button to bottom start
    ) {
        Text("I want to be at the bottom left")
    }
}


It all depends on the layout you want to use. Usually you don't want to position absolutely, but use a layout container instead that lays out its children. For what you want to achieve you can use a Column and set its verticalArrangement property accordingly. See the documentation for an animated overview of all available arrangements.
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
) {
    Text("I am at the top left")

    Text("Stuff in between")

    Text("I am at the bottom left")
}

